# (Javascript) Function with a prompt in it

Tags: javascript, function

Hello I am trying to write out a simple function but it will not work.

```
function username(a){
a = prompt ("What is your name?");
}
document.write ("Hello " + username(a));
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: You return nothing from your function. You assume that passing `a` is doing something.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "will not work".

Comment: @ScottHunter Just looking at the code you can tell why it does not work. :)

Comment: `username(a)` means you are _passing_ the value of a _to_ the function, not reading from it. Your code does the inverse of what you think it does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably should not pass *a*, instead return that from the function:

```js
function username(){
  var a = prompt ("What is your name?");
  return a;
}
document.write ("Hello " + username());
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `return` statement at end of function and also no need to pass argument to `username` function,

```js
function username(){
var a = prompt ("What is your name?");
return a;
}
document.write ("Hello " + username());
```